# Python swapping sequence double digits

Tags: python, double, swap, digits

Example of the code that works great

```
s="abc123"
swap_seq="103254"
swapped=''.join([s[int(i)] for i in swap_seq])
if s[0].isupper(): swapped.capitalize()
print (swapped)
```

but I have a large amount of characters that I need to be swapped 18 exactly, just wondering how to do the double digits

The example i'm trying to get it working with is the following.

```
s="0123456789abcdefgh"
swap_seq="1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6 9 8 11 10 13 12 15 14 17 16"
swapped=''.join([s[int(i)] for i in swap_seq])
if s[0].isupper(): swapped.capitalize()
print (swapped)
```

Tried ["0", "1", "2"]
but then the input would have to be exactly the same length or I get an error.

What i'm trying to do is have a user input anything up to 18 characters and the code will swap the letters/numbers around.

Comment: can't you just do `swap_seq = swap_seq.split()` first? that way it's a list instead of a string, then the rest of your logic should work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want, didn't try it. The way I read your code, you are indexing s, using the sequence outlined in `swap_seq`, so the `split` will give you a list of the positions, and i, instead of being each possible character in `swap_seq`, which includes spaces, will now be a list of the strings with the spaces taken out.

```
swapped=''.join([s[int(i)] for i in swap_seq.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

`swap_seq` shouldn't be a string. It's a sequence of index values so use a more appropriate data type, list a list of integers:

```py
swap_seq=[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 17, 16]
swapped=''.join([s[i] for i in swap_seq])
```